# jquery/javascript how to use $.each on a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with this jQuery code. The code below works fine but i tried to use $.each instead and its not working.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('#pull').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#pf').slideToggle();
    });
     $('#pullo').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#pt').slideToggle();
    });
      $('#pullc').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#pc').slideToggle();
    });

    $(document).click( function(){
        $('#pt').hide();
        $('#pf').hide();
        $('#pc').hide();
    });
});
```

The code below is not working for me, please help

```
var pul = ["#pull":"#pt","#pullo":"#pf", "#pullc":"#pc"];

$(document).ready( function(){

  $.each(pul, function(i, v){
    $(i).click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(v).slideToggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $(v).hide();

    });
  });  


});
```

Comment: Looks like your array syntax is invalid. You should curly braces for objects ("associative" arrays).

Comment: Your `pul` array should be an object, that's invalid JavaScript. It seems you want to refactor the script. Can you post the HTML?

Comment: It also looks like you mixed up `#pt` and `#pf`.

Comment: Just a note, when you click on the `document` *all* of your elements will `.hide()`.

Comment: Thank you , it's working now. Syntax error should have used {} instead of [] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var pul = {"#pull":"#pt","#pullo":"#pf", "#pullc":"#pc"};

$(document).ready( function(){

  $.each(pul, function(i, v){
    $(i).click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(v).slideToggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $(v).hide();

    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you , it's working now. Syntax error should have used {} instead of [] :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your collection object instead of array:

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/mZ35m/)

```
var pul = {"#pull":"#pt","#pullo":"#pf", "#pullc":"#pc"};

$(document).ready( function(){

  $.each(pul, function(i, v){
    $(i).click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(v).slideToggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $(v).hide();    
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$(''+i)` can just be `$(i)`.  No need to "convert" it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways you can solve this. Either make your array as 2D array:

```
var pul = [
    ["#pull", "#pt"],
    ["#pullo", "#pf"], 
    ["#pullc", "#pc"]];
```

And you can do `$(v[0]).click(...` instead of `$(i).click(...`. And `$(v[1]).hide();` instead of `$(v).hide();`.

Or, you can convert it to an object like others have suggested:

```
var pul = {"#pull":"#pt","#pullo":"#pf", "#pullc":"#pc"};
```

Right now, you have an invalid object and an invalid array.

Comment: I converted it to a valid object and its working now. Thank you